# Angular application not loading images in hosted apache server

Tags: angular, apache, web-hosting

I have an angular application and I run the `ng build --prod` command and deployed the files in the dist folder to the apache server /www/html/mywebsite folder in a ubuntu VM in DigitalOcean.

After the build of the angular application, the images called inside CSS files have come to the front directory even though originally they are in the assets directory as shown in the below screenshot.

Those images are showing fine without any issue in the website, but all the images called inside the HTML files are not displaying on the website. I don't think there is a permission issue to the assets folder because the javascript files inside the assets folder are loading without any issue. Here I have attached a screenshot of the permission of the files inside the assets folder.

Can you please help me to solve this?

[image: This is a screenshot of files inside the dist folder after the ng build --prod]

[image]

Comment: In the network tab, filter the request by image and check the error for those images. Post that screenshot if possible.

Comment: @RiteshWaghela It shows 404 Error in the status.

Comment: What path is building for those images? Also check your angular.json file where assets are configured.

Comment: @RiteshWaghela in the angular.json file,
"assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],

Comment: Have your index.html has base href set? what is the value?

Comment: It is   <base href="/html/sedsslweb/sedssl/">

Comment: @RiteshWaghela I think I got the issue with your guide. The paths showing the network tab is wrong for the images inside the assets folder. But the path of outside the asset folder are corret. Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting up base href value in your index.html file like this:

```
<base href="/sedsslweb/sedssl/">
```

in your template you will need to access images without a leading slash, like this, so that they will form correct path:

```
<img class="rounded-circle mx-auto" src="assets/images/Projects/serendib.png">
```

I just checked in dev tool by editing images path without leading slash, and could see the images loading fine.

Comment: Happy to help @Sanindu :)